# Precedence of assignment within a conditional operator

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I've created this simple program to auto-generate sequence of frames to be used in Avisynth scipt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    const int step = 3;
    const int arr[] = {31997, 31998, 32001};
    int i, ii = 0;

    for(i = 32002; i <= 32121; i += step, (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) - 1 ) != ii ? ++ii : ii = 0) {

        printf("freezeframe(%d,%d,%d)\n", i, i + step, arr[ii]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using MinGW with GCC 4.6.2, I get this error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

The issue is simply solved by using parenthesis around  *ii=0*. However, I don't get why it is an error. Shouldn't the assignment operator be evaluated first?

Comment: For writing code like that, you deserve to suffer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know. It was just for a simple task on hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikepedia has a short section which explains this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Notes

The grammar for conditional operator in C is

```
logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

Note that an `assignment-expression` *is not* considered a `conditional-expression`, and a conditional expression cannot be the left of an assignment expression and so it's technically a syntax error. See the grammar: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html

However, GCC is (incorrectly) parsing it as:

```
((sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) - 1 ) != ii ? ++ii : ii) = 0
```

Which is a semantic error since `++i` is not an lvalue expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's my my first time knowing that precedence is not the only that determine evaluation sequence.

Answer (score 4):

The conditional operator has higher precedence than the assignment operator in C.

```
(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) - 1 ) != ii ? ++ii : ii = 0
```

is evaluated as

```
((sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) - 1 ) != ii ? ++ii : ii) = 0
```

For a quick reminder of the operators precedence in C, you can see this:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/operator.7.html

Comment: "The conditional operator has higher precedence than the assignment operator in C." - actually, no. The precedence of operators in C depends on their context and cannot be correctly described simply by a precedence table. In fact, this code should compile fine.

Comment: @H2CO3 Why should it compile fine? Maybe in C++,but not C. See my answer.

Comment: @Pubby That's a good point, +1. (Yes, this is a compiler bug, indeed.)

Answer (score 0):

It is always advised to use parenthesis, if you write your code in this fashion

```
(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) - 1 ) != ii ? ++ii : ii = 0
```

like

```
(((sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) - 1 ) != ii ? ++ii : ii) = 0)
```

9 out of 10 times you will stuck.

So **make a habit of putting parenthesis** and this doesn't make any overhead on the compilers!!!